# Where is the option of Tracking's interface in Expression engine

Tags: php, codeigniter, expressionengine

I am trying to find option of Tracking views interface in expression engine I have enabled the tracking from `Admin->security and privacy->tracking preference` but I want to know where is the interface of tracking.
I found its **screenshot** here https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/5744/how-to-count-number-of-times-a-channel-entry-was-viewed-in-frontend but unable to find it in Expression engine.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Alas they are 2 different things.

The Control Panel menu link you reference here: `Admin->security and privacy->tracking preference` is referring to the native view tracking option (`Enable Channel Entry View Tracking?`), which you have to activate on any `channel:entries` tag calls when needed using the `track_views="one"` parameter.

More information and how to out the variable can be found [here](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/entry_tracking.html). I thought at one stage (may have been EE v1) that you could show the view count on the entries list within the Control Panel, but no longer there and can't find an add-on that does it...!?!

The screen grab and Control Panel interface from the link in your question is a [3rd party module](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/tracker) developed by SolSpace.